# Equation not showing

Tags: equations

I used the following code in overleaf but it isn't showing the requisite result. Any comments?

Let us label the two sides as A and B, and then define:

```
\begin{equation}

a_{_{i}}(t)= \begin{cases}

& 1, \text{ if side A is chosen}  \\

& (-1),  \text{ if side B is chosen} 

\end{cases}

\end{equation}
```

Comment: Do you really have blank lines in the input or is this just a by-product of the edit? And what's the problem? What's the required result like and what are you getting? No blank lines, `a_{_i}` should be `a_{i}` and there should be `&` before `\text`.

Comment: @egreg The `&` before `\text` would only make sense if `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` would be replaced with `\begin{align}...\end{align}`, or alternatively `\begin{split}...\end{split}` would be used within the `equation`-environment, wouldn't it!?

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf No, the `&` and ```\\``` is inside a `cases` environment.

Answer (score 3):

Did you `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % this is needed
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a_{_{i}}(t)= 
\begin{cases}
& 1, \text{ if side A is chosen} \\
& (-1), \text{ if side B is chosen}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```